# How to create a PNG image with HTML hex color fill?

Tags: python, image, colors

I have a script that generates a random hex code, and from that, I would like to generate an image with the generated color as the fill of the image. I looked at pylab, but was unable to get the result I was looking for. Could someone please assist me in figuring out how to do this?

Comment: What stops you from generating an rgb color instead.

Answer (score 4):

The Python Image Library (PIL, the maintained fork is called [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow)) can be used to create an image file.

Following https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#example-draw-a-gray-cross-over-an-image

```
from PIL import Image
webhexcolor = "#4878A8"
im = Image.new("RGB", (100,100), webhexcolor)
im.save( "color.png")
```

Comment: this seems like more of a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Providing an image library that allows OP to solve their problem counts as assistance in my view, but I have added code.

Answer (score 0):

Upvote if you find this useful:

```
#Hex to RGB
def hex_to_rgb(value):
    value = value.lstrip('#')
    lv = len(value)
    return tuple(int(value[i:i+lv//3], 16) for i in range(0, lv, lv//3))
print(hex_to_rgb("#0022ff"))

#https://www.codespeedy.com/create-random-hex-color-code-in-python/

import random
import cv2


def generate_random_hex():
    random_number = random.randint(0,16777215)
    hex_number = str(hex(random_number))
    hex_number ='#'+ hex_number[2:]
    print('A  Random Hex Color Code is :',hex_number)
    return hex_number

width1, height1 = 300, 300
random_hex_code=generate_random_hex()
random_rgb_code=hex_to_rgb(random_hex_code)
image = create_blank(width1, height1, rgb_color=random_rgb_code)
cv2.imwrite('random'+random_hex_code+'.jpg', image)
```

Comment: This is a bit late, but for generating the hex code if you're using this solution, you can also use `random.getrandbits(24)`